# PHP crypt password

Tags: php, criptografia

Eu tenho duas curiosidades acerca de encriptação de passes, eu tenho este este código:

1-
    $mainpass = "test123";

```
$md5pass = md5($mainpass);
$sha1pass = sha1($md5pass);
$cryptpass = crypt($sha1pass, 'st');

echo ($cryptpass);
```

Cujo o output é: 'stSuGIR46GScI'.

Mas não percebo porque este (em baixo) não é igual e o output está sempre a mudar:

```
$mainpass = "test123";
$cryptpass = crypt(sha1(md5($mainpass)));

echo ($cryptpass);
```

Pela minha lógica seria equivalente.

2- E na verificação e validação da palavra passe como mudaria o código em baixo que só tem md5 para corresponder à encriptação feita em cima (no caso correto)?

```
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
```

Comment: Já vi que responderam, mas surgiu uma preocupação, o exemplo é só mesmo para tentar entender o que se passa ou está sendo utilizado em produção? Tome cuidado ao utilizar o mesmo salt, é um erro. Procure sobre bcrypt.

Comment: Sim já ouvi falar, isto é para um CMS, o user vai ser só um, mas obgado pelo conelho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Caso 1:

No primeiro exemplo, você está adicionando um Salt ('st') ao chamar a função `crypt`. Acredito que o problema esteja aí, já que é a única diferença visível. Mude o segundo exemplo para:

```
$cryptpass = crypt(sha1(md5($mainpass)), 'st');
```

### Caso 2:

Seguindo a mesma lógica, altere a linha na qual a senha é definida:

```
$password = crypt(sha1(md5($_POST['password'])), 'st');
```

Comment: Claro o 'st'... Muito obgado @Michael